# Django Paypal Import Error

Tags: django, django-paypal

Probably, it's stupid question. I'm using Django 1.7 & Python 2.7. I have successfull installed django 0.1.5 by running python manage.py runserver / validate. However, when I open up my view **I got No module named standard.forms** error. I'm using virtualenvwrapper as well. Can someone help me to shed any light?

```
Environment:

Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/manager/paypal_payment/

Django Version: 1.7.1
Python Version: 2.7.8
Installed Applications:
('profilesite','portal','manager','qrcode','account','paypal.standard.ipn','django.contrib.admin','django.contrib.auth','django.contrib.contenttypes','django.contrib.sessions','django.contrib.messages','django.contrib.staticfiles')

Installed Middleware:
('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware','django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware','django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
 'account.middleware.LocaleMiddleware',
 'account.middleware.TimezoneMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "/Users/eeldwin/.virtualenvs/fbt/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
98. resolver_match = resolver.resolve(request.path_info)
File "/Users/eeldwin/.virtualenvs/fbt/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in resolve 
345. sub_match = pattern.resolve(new_path)
File "/Users/eeldwin/.virtualenvs/fbt/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in resolve
345.sub_match = pattern.resolve(new_path)
File "/Users/eeldwin/.virtualenvs/fbt/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in resolve
224. return ResolverMatch(self.callback, args, kwargs, self.name)
File "/Users/eeldwin/.virtualenvs/fbt/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in callback
231. self._callback = get_callable(self._callback_str)
File "/Users/eeldwin/.virtualenvs/fbt/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/lru_cache.py" in wrapper
101. result = user_function(*args, **kwds)
File "/Users/eeldwin/.virtualenvs/fbt/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in get_callable
  97.             mod = import_module(mod_name)
File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py" in import_module
  37.     __import__(name)
File "/Users/eeldwin/Documents/Django/fbt/manager/views/pp_ipn.py" in <module>
  1. from paypal.standard.forms import PayPalPaymentsForm

Exception Type: ImportError at /manager/paypal_payment/
Exception Value: No module named standard.forms
```

Comment: Make sure that you don't have a `paypal.py` file in your apps

Comment: Yes, that's the problem. I changed the paypal.py several hours ago, but I forgot to delete .pyc file. Thanks for answer, it's been OK now.

Comment: You should add your answer and mark it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that you don't have a paypal.py file in your apps. If that's the case, you'll need to delete paypal.pyc too.